# How do you access an IPython Notebook remotely?

Tags: ssh, ipython, jupyter-notebook, remote-access

Is it possible to have an IPython notebook upon in your own local browser, but it is running on a remote machine?

How does one actually access an IPython notebook running remotely using `ssh`?

Answer (score 1):

Quoth the extensive [Jupyter Documentation for Running a Notebook Server](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html):

> The Jupyter notebook web application is based on a server-client structure. The notebook server uses a two-process kernel architecture based on ZeroMQ, as well as Tornado for serving HTTP requests.
>
> This document describes how you can secure a notebook server and how to run it on a public interface.

Comment: My understanding is that this can run the Jupyter notebook on the server, dettached from the terminal. However, you cannot actually view and manipulate the said notbeook in your own local browser, but the kernel, etc. runs on the remote server. 
Correct me if I'm wrong though please.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your iPython notebook on GitHub or GitHub Gist or any file service (DropBox) then you can point http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ to your file and view it online.

Or you can export your notebook to HTML https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html

this may be less necessary as GitHub displays iPython notebooks directly now (try https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_pycon2015/blob/master/notebooks/02.1-Machine-Learning-Intro.ipynb)

The code for nbViewer is also on GitHub https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer

---

Let me know if you need to *modify* notebooks remotely or just view them.